# Multiple histogram plots using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
x <- data.frame("raw_A" = runif(20, 2, 10), "raw_B" = runif(20, 2, 10), "mod_A" = runif(20, 2, 10), "mod_B" = runif(20, 2, 10), "modmod_A" = runif(20, 2, 10), "modmod_B" = runif(20, 2, 10), "raw_C"
    = runif(20, 2, 10), "raw_D" = runif(20, 2, 10), "mod_C" = runif(20, 2, 10), "mod_D" = runif(20, 2, 10), "modmod_C" = runif(20, 2, 10), "modmod_D" = runif(20, 2, 10), "raw_E" = runif(20, 2, 10), "raw_F" = runif(20, 2, 10), "mod_E" = runif(20, 2, 10), "mod_F" = runif(20, 2, 10), "modmod_E" = runif(20, 2, 10), "modmod_F" = runif(20, 2, 10))
```

What I would like to do it so use ggplot to plot a series of histograms

```
geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.8, bins = 100)
```

(A vs B, C vs D, and E vs F).

Using `facet_wrap` I want in the first column A vs B, in the second column C vs D and in the third E vs F.

At the same time in the first row I want `raw_`, in the second row `mod_` and in the last row `modmod_`

such as

```
raw_A vs raw_B       |       raw_C vs raw_D       |       raw_E vs raw_F

mod_A vs mod_B       |       mod_C vs mod_D       |       mod_E vs mod_F

modmod_A vs modmod_B |    modmod_C vs modmod_D    |    modmod_E vs modmod_F
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There’s no need to quote your column names. The fact that R even allows this is a flaw in the language specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you would require only specific combinations of the variables, it would be better to do it selectively. One option could be generating the dataset as required:

```
df <- rbind(data.frame(x=x$raw_A, y=x$raw_B, comb='raw_A vs raw_B'),
            data.frame(x=x$raw_C, y=x$raw_D, comb='raw_C vs raw_D'),
            data.frame(x=x$raw_E, y=x$raw_F, comb='raw_E vs raw_F'),

            data.frame(x=x$mod_A, y=x$mod_B, comb='mod_A vs mod_B'),
            data.frame(x=x$mod_C, y=x$mod_D, comb='mod_C vs mod_D'),
            data.frame(x=x$mod_E, y=x$mod_F, comb='mod_E vs mod_F'),

            data.frame(x=x$modmod_A, y=x$modmod_B, comb='modmod_A vs modmod_B'),
            data.frame(x=x$modmod_C, y=x$modmod_D, comb='modmod_C vs modmod_D'),
            data.frame(x=x$modmod_E, y=x$modmod_F, comb='modmod_E vs modmod_F')
            )
```

Then plotting using the facet variable `comb` created using the required combinations

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~comb)
```

[image]

---

The distribution of values generated in your example are strictly within the range `2-10`, generated randomly using `runif(20, 2, 10)`. But, in other scenarios, if the distribution of the variables are not strict like this, you can use the `scales` option.

Assume you have generated the data for the below variables with different ranges and the rest same as in original dataset.

```
        "modmod_A" = runif(20, 2, 6), "modmod_B" = runif(20, 2, 6), 
        "modmod_C" = runif(20, 2, 6), "modmod_D" = runif(20, 2, 6), 
        "modmod_E" = runif(20, 2, 6), "modmod_F" = runif(20, 2, 6)
```

You can see the difference in the below two plots.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~comb)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~comb, scales="free")
```

[image]